# Prove continuous at 0 using Epsilon Delta definition of limit

Tags: calculus

How would one approach this problem?

For a function $f$ where $k>0$ such that $|f(x)| <k\cdot|x|$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. Use the epsillon delta definition of the limit to show that $f$ is continous at $0$

Comment: Well a function is continuous if  $$ \lim_{x\to c} {f(x)} = f(c)$$  I'm just not sure how to structure this proof

Comment: Actually the proof is immediate by squeezing.

Comment: Okay... now you need to give us the definition of the limit.

Comment: First you will need to quote the defitions of limit and continuity let your reader know what you intend to show.  Then you will say something along the lines of:  let $\delta = \frac \epsilon k, x<\delta \implies |f(x)|<\epsilon$ .  Then you will say that all of the criteria of the definitions have been met.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense as stated.  For $f$ to be continuous at $0$ we need to be able to say something about $f(0)$, but the condition forces $f(0)$ to not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$|f(x)-0| < k|x-0|$$

$|x-0| < \delta \implies |f(x)-0|< k\delta$.

Try to think of a way to choose $\delta$ such that $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Sure, but this only proves that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0$.  What is $f(0)$?

Comment: This was also a concern of mine.  I'm thinking that we should be able to deduce that $f(0)$ is indeed equal to $0$, since we are are given the inequality $|f(x)| \leq k|x|$, which implies that for the absolute value of $f(0)$ to be less than or equal to $k|0|$, it too must be equal to $0$

Comment: @ErickWong you are right, we need to change the question from $<$ to $\leq$.

Comment: @johnfowles We are given that it is strictly less than $0$, which is impossible :).